# Lisp S-Expressions and Lists Length/Size

Tags: list, lisp, common-lisp, s-expression

I am trying to write a function using Common Lisp functions only that will count how many s-expressions are in an s-expression. For example:

```
((x = y)(z = 1)) ;; returns 2
```

and

```
((x - y)) ;; returns 1
```

Nested expressions are possible so:

```
((if x then (x = y)(z = w))) ;; returns 3
```

I wrote a function which finds the length and it works if no nested expressions are there. It is:

```
(define (length exp)
  (cond
    ((null? exp) 0)
    (#t (+ 1 (length (cdr exp))))))
```

Now I modified this in an attempt to support nested expressions to the following:

```
(define (length exp)
  (cond
    ((null? exp) 0)
    ((list? (car exp)) (+ 1 (length (cdr exp))))
    (#t (length (cdr exp)))))
```

This works for expressions with no nests, but is always 1 less than the answer for nested expressions. This is because taking the example above, `((if x then (x = y)(z = w)))`, this will look at `if` at first and which satisfies the third condition, returning the cdr (the rest of the expression as a list) into `length`. The same happens up until (x=y) is reached, at which point a `+1` is returned. This means that the expression `(if x then .... )` has not been counted.

In what ways would I be able to account for it? Adding `+2` will over-count un-nested expressions.

I will need this to work in one function as nesting can happen anywhere, so:

```
((x = y) (if y then (z = w)))
```

Comment: This looks strange. You say 'I am trying to write a function using Common Lisp functions only'. Yet, your code is in Scheme?

Comment: @RainerJoswig my code is in scheme but I'm only using LISP numeric primitives, predicates and functions.

Comment: okay, but this has nothing to do with Common Lisp. Common Lisp has a lot of functions - more than an educational Scheme.

Comment: @RainerJoswig Alright - I really don't know the difference, I just got started with Scheme.

Answer (score 2):

At first sight, your code only recurses to the right (cdr-side) and not to the left (car-side), so that definitely is a problem there.

On second sight, this is even a little bit more tricky than that, because you are not exactly counting conses; you need to differentiate the case where a cons starts a proper list vs where it's the cdr of a list. If you were to recurse to the car and cdr, that information would be lost. We need to iterate over the sexp as a proper list,

```
(defun count-proper-list (sexp)
  (cond ((atom sexp) 0)
        (t (1+ (reduce #'+ (mapcar #'count-proper-list sexp))))))
```

But this will also count the top level list, therefor always return one more than what you seem to want.  So perhaps,

```
(defun count-proper-sublist (sexp)
  (1- (count-proper-list sexp)))
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure what mapcar or reduce do, but I'm not allowed to use them for this. I see where my problem is. It's that I'm missing some lists or elements in my recursion. Speaking conceptually, I need to walk the sexp as a proper list. 1- How is that done? 2- How would I still detect nested sexps? Sorry I didn't get it all.